# ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded on update mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, timeout, locking

I am running following update -

`update table_x set name= 'xyz' where id = 121;`

and getting - 
`ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

I googled it number of times and adding extra time to `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` not helping me out.

Please let me know the root cause of this issue and how I can solve it.
I am using mysql 5.6(master-master replication) on dedicated server.
Also table_x(Innodb table) heavily used in database. Autocommit is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I tried different values for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, also tried to change queries but got the same error. I did some research and asked my colleagues about hibernate.

They were doing numbers of transaction which include updating main table and committing in the end. So, I suggested them to use commit on each transaction. Finally I am not getting any lock wait time out errors.

Answer (score 2):

Find out what other statement is running at the same time as this `UPDATE`.  It sounds as if it is running a long time *and* hanging onto the rows that this `UPDATE` needs.  Meanwhile this statement is waiting.

One way to see it is to do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` while the `UPDATE` is hung.

(In my opinion, the default of 50 seconds for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` is much to high.  Raising the value only aggravates the situation.)

If you give up on fixing the 'root cause' of the conflict, then you might tackle the issue a different way.

1. *Lower* `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` to, say, 5.
2. Programmatically catch the error when it times out and restart the `UPDATE`.
3. Do likewise for all other transactions.  Other queries may also be piling up; restarting some may "uncork" the problem.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tx_isolation';` -- There *may* be a better setting for it, especially if a long-running `SELECT` is the villain.

Comment: what will be other side effects of `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` to 5?
my current `tx_isolation` is `repeatable_read`. Should I change it to `read-commited`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some lock on any of your other transaction. You can check the status of INNODB by using this:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

Check if there is any lock on the tables like this:

```
show open tables where in_use>0;
```

And then kill that processes which are locked.

Comment: can we achieve it without killing process?? 
Suppose scheduler runs at midnight and we are not monitoring, it will run as per schedule but after lock wait time out, it will stop.
In this case how we can solve this issue?

Comment: @Aamir:- In that case my suggestion would be check for the isolation level in the mysql cli. Refer this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html

Comment: (Re: midnight run)  The code should check for errors -- on lock timeout and deadlock, restart the transaction.  But... since this is an automated task, don't restart more than once or twice -- something _could_ cause it to get in a loop.  So, after a small number of retries, dump some things (`SHOW ENGINE INNODB_STATUS`, code line number, etc) and abort.